# Getting the reward points of a validator by account

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js

I am trying to find the reward points belonging to a validator. I started with this:

```
const activeEra = await api.query.staking.activeEra()

const rewardPoints = await api.query.staking.erasRewardPoints(activeEra.unwrap().index)
const individualRewardPoints = activeEraRewardPoints.individual
```

Now, it looks like the `individualRewardPoints` is some kind of map keyed by validator accounts, however I couldn't find how to get the specific item (I don't want to iterate over the map). Having a string, I tried these:

```
const alice = '5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY'

individualRewardPoints.get(alice)
individualRewardPoints.get(Buffer.from(alice))
```

This looked promising but still doesn't work:

```
{ decodeAddress } = require ('@polkadot/keyring')
individualRewardPoints.get(decodeAddress(alice))
```

All of them return `undefined`. What's the way to get the reward points of a validator?

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into this same challenge and unfortunately I did not find away around iterating through.

`eraRewardPoints.individual` is [a `BTreeMap<AccountId, RewardPoint>`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/types/src/codec/BTreeMap.ts), so the key should be an `AccountId`. Under the hood this BTreeMap is [represented by a JS Map](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/1abc5192972bb424087fe7f8226f8aab1a787bf9/packages/types/src/codec/Map.ts#L92) and in TS we see that it has `AccountId` as its key type. To create that type we could do `api.createType('AccountId', alice)`. However, for me creating the type and using it to key in did not work. My guess is that it creates a new object that JS does not recognize as the same `AccountId` object as in the map.

So my solution was:

```js
for (const [id, points] of eraRewardPoints.individual.entries()) {
  if (id.toString() === validatorId) {
    return points;
  }
}
```

You can find the exact code in substrate-api-sidecar, which has an endpoint (`accounts/{accountId}/staking-payouts`) that gives the payout for an address using arithmetic done in Rust: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/ee0a0488bf8100a42e713fc287f08d72394677b9/src/services/accounts/AccountsStakingPayoutsService.ts#L301